# How to capture data change in yugabyte db?

Tags: yugabytedb

terminal 1:

```
postgres=# \c yugastore
You are now connected to database "yugastore" as user "postgres".
yugastore=# select count(*) from yugastore.users;
 count 
-------
  2500
(1 row)

yugastore=# delete from yugastore.users;
DELETE 2500

(After starting insertion script at terminal 2)

yugastore=# select count(*) from yugastore.users;
ERROR:  Query error: Restart read required at: { read: { physical: 1580057095845877 } local_limit: { physical: 1580057095880226 } global_limit: <min> in_txn_limit: <max> serial_no: 0 }
yugastore=# select count(*) from yugastore.users;
ERROR:  Query error: Restart read required at: { read: { physical: 1580057098605539 } local_limit: { physical: 1580057098715271 } global_limit: <min> in_txn_limit: <max> serial_no: 0 }
```

terminal2:

yugastore.users table is created and being populated.

```
time: 11:44:31.796 cumulative records: 100
time: 11:44:32.608 cumulative records: 200
time: 11:44:32.909 cumulative records: 300
time: 11:44:33.213 cumulative records: 400
time: 11:44:33.661 cumulative records: 500
...
time: 11:46:24.710 cumulative records: 18900
time: 11:46:25.137 cumulative records: 19000
time: 11:46:25.606 cumulative records: 19100
```

terminal 3:

```
[root@srvr0 ~]# java -jar ./yb_cdc_connector.jar --table_name yugastore.users --master_addrs 127.0.0.1:7100 --log_only
[2020-01-26 11:45:57,844] INFO Starting CDC Kafka Connector... (org.yb.cdc.Main:28)
2020-01-26 11:45:58,201 [INFO|org.yb.cdc.KafkaConnector|KafkaConnector] Creating new YB client...
[2020-01-26 11:46:02,853] INFO Discovered tablet YB Master for table YB Master with partition ["", "") (org.yb.client.AsyncYBClient:1593)
[2020-01-26 11:46:03,724] ERROR [Peer fakeUUID -> 127.0.0.1:9100] Tablet server sent error Invalid argument (yb/rpc/yb_rpc.cc:411): Call on service yb.cdc.CDCService received from Connection (0x0000000005b8e2d0) server 127.0.0.1:46926 => 127.0.0.1:9100 with an invalid method name: CreateCDCStream (org.yb.client.TabletClient:380)
2020-01-26 11:46:03,725 [ERROR|org.yb.cdc.Main|Main] Application ran into error: 
org.yb.client.NonRecoverableException: [Peer fakeUUID -> 127.0.0.1:9100] Tablet server sent error Invalid argument (yb/rpc/yb_rpc.cc:411): Call on service yb.cdc.CDCService received from Connection (0x0000000005b8e2d0) server 127.0.0.1:46926 => 127.0.0.1:9100 with an invalid method name: CreateCDCStream
    at org.yb.client.TabletClient.decode(TabletClient.java:379)
    at org.yb.client.TabletClient.decode(TabletClient.java:98)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.yb.client.TabletClient.handleUpstream(TabletClient.java:608)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.messageReceived(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:184)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.yb.client.AsyncYBClient$TabletClientPipeline.sendUpstream(AsyncYBClient.java:2002)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Update1:

After installing yugabyte db 2.0.10.0, error "Restart read required" resolved but no change logs printed:

Error logs:

```
[root@srvr0 ~]# java -jar ./yb-cdc-connector.jar --table_name yugastore.users --master_addrs 127.0.0.1:7100 --stream_id 1 --log_only
[2020-01-28 08:27:31,101] INFO Starting CDC Kafka Connector... (org.yb.cdc.Main:28)
2020-01-28 08:27:31,154 [INFO|org.yb.cdc.KafkaConnector|KafkaConnector] Creating new YB client...
[2020-01-28 08:27:32,288] INFO Discovered tablet YB Master for table YB Master with partition ["", "") (org.yb.client.AsyncYBClient:1593)
2020-01-28 08:27:32,597 [INFO|org.yb.cdc.KafkaConnector|KafkaConnector] Polling for new tablet ce5115a780224cd0ab8a8e9c1a46b961
2020-01-28 08:27:32,604 [INFO|org.yb.cdc.KafkaConnector|KafkaConnector] Polling for new tablet cca5b30bb7784ae2a8796097d6fd5b2f
2020-01-28 08:27:32,694 [ERROR|org.yb.cdc.Poller|Poller] Invalid Request
2020-01-28 08:27:32,695 [ERROR|org.yb.cdc.Poller|Poller] Invalid Request
[root@srvr0 ~]#
```

Please help me in resolving the issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The read restart issue that you see with `select count(*) ..` query has been fixed and is available from version 2.0.5.2: https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/commit/3212616e351647436f808d4963d229e7881996c8.

Similarly, it seems like you are using an older, deprecated version of the CDC connector. You can get the connector using:
`wget -O yb-cdc-connector.jar https://github.com/yugabyte/yb-kafka-connector/blob/master/yb-cdc/yb-cdc-connector.jar?raw=true`

And then run:
`java -jar ./yb-cdc-connector.jar --table_name yugastore.users --master_addrs 127.0.0.1:7100 --log_only`

Comment: added section Update1. Please help me in resolving Invalid Request issue.