# How to configure yb-cdc-connector to resume printing logs upon yugabyte db restart (stop and start)?

Tags: yugabytedb

Following, [How to capture data change in yugabyte db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920570/how-to-capture-data-change-in-yugabyte-db)
to publish the change logs.

It works properly. But, yb-connector.jar is not resuming the publishing change data logs, after restarting yugabyte db.

Commands Executed:

```
wget -O yb-cdc-connector.jar https://github.com/yugabyte/yb-kafka-connector/blob/master/yb-cdc/yb-cdc-connector.jar?raw=true
```

terminal1:

```
###start yugabyte db
/opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-2.0.10.0/bin/yb-ctl --data_dir "/opt/yugabyte/data" start
```

terminal2:

```
###start load generator
julia "/root/gen_users_yb.jl"
```

terminal3:

```
###publish change logs
java -jar ./yb-cdc-connector.jar --table_name yugastore.users --master_addrs 127.0.0.1:7100 --log_only
```

terminal1:

```
###stop yugabyte db
/opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-2.0.10.0/bin/yb-ctl --data_dir "/opt/yugabyte/data" stop
```

(Note: upon LibPQ Exception load generator exits and yb-connector waits)

terminal2:

```
###restarting load generator
julia "/root/gen_users_yb.jl"
```

Observation: No resumption in publishing logs on terminal 3

Please help me in configure yb-cdc-connector resume printing logs upon yb-ctl restart (stop and start).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't yet supported. Can you create an issue on github https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues ?